Mesh analysis with voltage sources
I'm trying to find the current in both resistors. Unfortunately I'm not getting the answers I want.

I have taken the current direction from positive to negative terminal
and \begin{align}
I_{1},
I_{2}
\end{align} running in clockwise direction.
Here are the equations I have written. The first one is for the left loop and the second one for the right loop.
\begin{align}
20I_{1} - I_{2} &= 10 \\
40I_{2} - I_{1} &= -10
\end{align}
But on solving them I don't get the values right.
Here are the right values.
\begin{align}
I_{1} &= 0.5 \\
I_{2} &= 0
\end{align}
What I'm doing wrong?

You seem to have used mesh analysis incorrectly.In Mesh analysis, currents are assumed to be always on in a mesh. You have two mesh in the circuit. When you come across as branch in which current from two branches are circulating, you subtract one current from another. The current which has to be subtracted from the other is dependent on the orientation of the mesh while you use KVL.
Assume current \$I_1\$ in mesh on left and assume current \$I_2\$ in mesh on right, both circulating in clockwise directions.
Using KVL in both mesh 1 and 2 and using passive sign convention,
$$ -10 + 20 (I_1 - I_2) = 0   $$
$$ 20I_2 + 20(I_2 - I_1) + 10 = 0 $$
Observe that in the second equation, the 20 ohm resistor in the middle has the current \$I_2 - I_1 \$ while applying KVL in mesh 2 as opposed to  \$I_1 - I_2 \$ while applying KVL in mesh 1. The current depends on your direction of applying Kirchoff's voltage law.
Rearranging the equations,
$$  20 I_1 - 20I_2 = 10$$
$$ - 20I_1 + 40I_2 = -10 $$
You can solve from here.

You have made some big errors not least the incorrect way you have handled I2. Here's my first solution: -

Clearly, I2 equals zero (as you can tell by just looking at the image.
Or, do it the other way round and you get the same story: -

